# Google Map is not showing on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, firefox

I am using google map api to generate map. By using following code i am able to generate map on google chrome, but it is not working in firefox. Furthermore there is no JS error on console and corresponding html in not generating on firefox.

```
var map;
var marker;
var lat;
var lng;
var myLatlng;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize(){

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.69748,133.88362);
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        show_map(lat,lng);
    }

    function show_map(lat,lng){

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
        map.setZoom(8);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            draggable: true
        });

        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng) }, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }

        });

    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Could you post some fiddle?

Comment: geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); and infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  -- Try putting those lines inside of initialize(). (you can keep the declaration global).

Comment: If `navigator.geolocation` is false then you dont call `show_map` with the `myLatlng` as a possition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the initialize method like `initialize();`, and it will work.

I've made you a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0fq4rf/).